# Using namespaces in inline assembly

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

Let's say i have the following inline assembly code...

```
_asm {
    fst  dword ptr [eax]mystruct1.mymember
    fstp dword ptr [ebx]mystruct2.mymember
}
```

... but unfortunately mystruct1 and mystruct2 both have the same name and are in different namespaces. I tried like this...

```
_asm {
    fst  dword ptr [eax]mynamespace1::mystruct.mymember
    fstp dword ptr [ebx]mynamespace2::mystruct.mymember
}
```

...but it doesn't work. Is it possible to somehow specify namespace without a c++ using statement (that wouldn't work anyway, because you'd somehow need to change namespace used between operations)?
And no, I can't change namespace, struct or member names.

Comment: 1. Why are you using inline assembly? 2. You probably need to use mangled name which even further reduces portability.

Comment: Try using `typedef`s in the local scope of the function.

Comment: I'm using inline assembly because my job requires me to. It's a Windows driver, so I couldn't care less about portability. And no, you don't need to use mangled names; other instructions accept namespaces (example: `jmp [mynamespace::mystruct::mystaticmember]`).

Comment: Ah, totally forgot I could just typedef them to a different name. Cheers, Paul!

Comment: @kingofx I don't think you can use `typedef` on variables, can you? Or is `mystruct` not a variable?

Comment: No, no, it's a type name and eax is a pointer to a struct of type mystruct. The inline assembly syntax MSVC uses to access struct members is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to create a reference and use that instead:

```
MyStruct& ms = mynamespace1::mystruct;

_asm {
    fst  dword ptr [eax]ms.mymember
    fstp dword ptr [ebx]ms.mymember
}
```

I don't know if this is possible in your situation though.